# In a Java unit test, how do I assert a number is within a given range?

Tags: java, junit

Coming to Java from Python. I recognize this is pretty basic, but it doesn't seem this has been asked here yet and Google is being coy with me.

In Python, I'd simply do something like this but Java objects:

```
assertTrue(min <= mynum and mynum <= max);
```

Comment: Because `and` is not a Java keyword.  You want `&&`.

Comment: Ah, yes. `import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue` also helped. Thanks all!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd write:

```
assertTrue("mynum is out of range: " + mynum, min <= mynum && mynum <= max);
```

but technically you just need:

```
assertTrue(min <= mynum && mynum <= max);
```

Either way, be sure to write `&&` and not `and`.

Answer (score 21):

I will use [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/wiki) as Jonathan said, but with simpler assertions :)

```
 assertThat(mynum).isBetween(min, max);
```

I think this is the coolest solution :)

Answer (score 7):

you can use [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) library too ,this is more readable.

```
assertThat(mynum,greaterThanOrEqualTo(min));

assertThat(mynum,lessThanOrEqualTo(max));
```

Those lines can be merged via `allOf` like this:

```
assertThat(mynum, allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(min),lessThanOrEqualTo(max)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Extending on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714324/891292) answer: you can combine the two with `allOf`.

```
assertThat(mynum, allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(min),lessThanOrEqualTo(max)));
```

The OR equivalent in Hamcrest is `anyOf`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [AssertJ](http://assertj.org/) it becomes *even* more readable:

```
assertThat(mynum).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(min).isLessThanOrEqualTo(max);
```

Plus the `AssertionError` beats the `assertTrue` version as you don't need to supply a description, e.g.:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
 <10>
to be less than or equal to:
 <42>
```

If you're using Java 8 and AssertJ 3.0.0, you can use a lambda to specify it:

```
assertThat(mynum).matches(actual -> actual >= min && actual <= max);
```

Comment: How is that error more readable? 10 is less than or equal to 42 so that is just confusing.

Comment: I that the assertion reads more naturally compared to the `assertTrue` and Hamcrest versions.

Answer (score 2):

Using **AssertJ** with `isCloseTo(expected, offset)`:

```
BigDecimal maxNegativeOffset = new BigDecimal("0.0004");
BigDecimal actual = new BigDecimal("0.0005");
BigDecimal maxPositiveOffset = new BigDecimal("0.0006");

Offset<BigDecimal> offset = Offset.offset(new BigDecimal("0.0001"));

Assertions.assertThat(actual)
  .isCloseTo(maxNegativeOffset, offset)
  .isCloseTo(maxPositiveOffset, offset);
```

Maven dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution and was not satisfied with the existing ones. In JUnit5 it is possible to achieve exactly the required functionality with `assertEquals`

```
// Asserts that expected and actual are equal within the given delta. 
assertEquals(expected, actual, delta);
```

With `expected` being `(min + max) / 2.0`, and `delta` `(max - min) / 2.0`.
For example, if you want to check that `actual` is between 1.0 and 4.0, you could write:

```
assertEquals(2.5, actual, 1.5);
```

You can find more information in the [JUnit5 Docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-double-double-double-)

Comment: Hi, I had a similar issue as the posted question and read some articles about using `assertEquals(expected, actual, delta)` with a "delta" value. It seems the delta/epsilon means the acceptable precision or accepted margin of error of the actual output.  Could you please explain how I can use this function for a scenario, such as mentioned below.  E.g.: The value of a variable "position" must be between MIN_POSITION = 1 and MAX_POSITION = 4.

Comment: @hel: You'd use `assertEquals(2.5, actual, 1.5)`. Which might not be very clear at first that it means that actual is between 1 and 4. But at least you don't need any other library or complex syntax.

Comment: @EricDuminil :  Thank you for the example. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

`assertTrue(min <= mynum && mynum <= max, "not in range");`

the comment at the end is optional.  Basically the same as the python version, except the `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&&` rather than `and`; other than that, what you wrote should work.

Answer (score 1):

From [Truth](https://truth.dev/faq#floating-point)

```
import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;

assertThat(actualDouble).isWithin(tolerance).of(expectedDouble);

assertThat(0.0999999).isWithin(1E-6).of(0.1d);

assertThat(90d).isWithin(10d).of(100d);   // success
assertThat(105d).isWithin(10d).of(100d);  // success
assertThat(110d).isWithin(10d).of(100d);  // success

assertThat(89d).isWithin(10d).of(100d);   // fails
assertThat(111d).isWithin(10d).of(100d);  // fails
java.lang.AssertionError: <111.0> and <100.0> should have been finite values within <10.0> of each other
```